# Installing IBM mobile first in DST server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am developing an mobile application using IBM Mobile First 7.0 .Now I need to move it to a Production environment in DST environment. I already have a DST environment which is running on AIX -7.1. I searched for some installation guide to install the Mobile first in the DST environment but I couldn't find any.Can someone provide me the guidance or support document which will help me to configure the WL server in the WAS environment.

Comment: Are we supposed to know what is "dst environment"?

Comment: What is DST environment?

Comment: DST is nothing but a cloud based environment with WAS server

Comment: all i need is how to move my application to production. Like how to install mobile first in the production environment

Answer (score 0):

> all i need is how to move my application to production. Like how to
>   install mobile first in the production environment

You can find detailed installation instructions, here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/topics/c_install_config.html

Since you did not properly explain your situation in the question, follow the instructions. Once you have a detailed question with a problem, error, logs, etc... ask again.